# How do i manipulate data or values of collection view items?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am developing an application in .NET MAUI and i have a page with a collection view which is loaded with data. I display the data onto the collection view children. But then i have a problem, I have a stepper and i want when i change the stepper value, the label i named priceLabel to also change in this format (priceLabelValue = new stepper value * price of the current displayed item of collection view). I also have another label outside the collection view and i want to display on it the total price of all items in the collection view.

I have tried all ways i think but all in vain, one of the problems i encountered was that i was unable to access the views i created within the collection view from the code behind.

When i tried to update these children views using the view model i also found out that i could not
access the current item of collection view from the view model.

HINT: Am developing a cart page for products.... Hope this will also help

This is my code.

// xaml code

```
<CollectionView     x:Name="collcn"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingBagCollection}"
                             Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            EmptyView="NO ITEMS ADDED">
                    


            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Cloth">


                   
                       <Grid Padding="0"
                          Grid.ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
                          Grid.RowDefinitions="*,*,*"
                          ColumnSpacing="10"        
                          HeightRequest="160"       
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          Margin="20,20,0,20">


                                <Frame Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.RowSpan="3"
                               Style="{StaticResource CardView}"
                               Margin="30"        
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               IsClippedToBounds="True">


                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
                                       Aspect="Fill"
                                       HeightRequest="100"
                                       WidthRequest="100"/>

                                </Frame>
                                <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                                             Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                             Spacing="5"
                                             HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                             Margin="0,20,20,0">

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"
                                           Grid.Row="0"/>
                              
                           <!-- This label displays current value of stepper-->

                            <Label x:Name="stepperValue"  
                                           Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}" 
                                           Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference stepper}, Path=Value}"/>

                        
                            <Stepper x:Name="stepper"
                                              Grid.Row="1"
                                              Minimum="1"
                                              Maximum="{Binding Quantity}"
                                              Increment="1"/>

          <!-- This label should display current value of stepper * Price of current Item-->

                            <Label x:Name="price"  
                                   Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}" 
                                   Grid.Row="2"       
                                   Text="{Binding Price}"/>

                        </VerticalStackLayout>

    </Grid>
  
                </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>


        <Grid            
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                          Grid.Row="2"
                          Padding="0"
                          Grid.ColumnDefinitions="*,*"
                          Grid.RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*"
                          ColumnSpacing="0"
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          Margin="20">
        
                <VerticalStackLayout   
                           Grid.RowSpan="4"
                           Grid.Column="0">


 
<!-- This entry should display total price of all items in collection view but i have failed to get a walk around-->

                <Entry x:Name="totalcostLabel"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Placeholder="$0.00"   
                       Margin="0,30,0,0"
                       Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference collcn}}"
                       WidthRequest="120"                      
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       IsReadOnly="True"
                       Style="{StaticResource MediumLabel}"/>
                    
                <Label Grid.Row="2"
                       Text="TotalCost" 
                       Margin="0"/>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
```

// view model
I think there is no need to post the view model and code behind because there is no special logic i have added after trying on so many different ways.

Any body to help me and tell me how l can go about that many thanks in advance.

Comment: the entire point of MVVM is that you update the model, and the UI refreshes to reflect that.  You do not directly manipulate the UI.  Since you have not posted your VM its very difficult to give you any concrete advice.

Comment: ensure that your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`,and uses it for its properties and that it holds collections of data within `ObservableCollections`. View data is retrieved by binding to the properties of the `DataContext` which you set to the ViewModel. The ViewModel does not rely on the View. `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation also means that logic within the ViewModel can run asynchronously to the UI code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue based on your code and found a solution to make it, though there might be other solutions. Try the following code:

First, in your .xaml file, for your stepper add a ValueChanged event, that's **stepper_ValueChanged**, which would be triggered while the value of stepper changes.

```
<Stepper x:Name="stepper"                                             
         Grid.Row="1"
         Minimum="1"
         Maximum="{Binding Quantity}"
         Increment="1"                                 
         ValueChanged="stepper_ValueChanged"/>
```

Then, in .cs file, we generate a **stepper_ValueChanged** (or automatically generated by vs).

```
MainPageViewModel vm;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new MainPageViewModel();
    this.BindingContext = vm;
}

private void stepper_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double pricetotal = 0;  
    
    // The BindingContext of each stepper is Cloth instance in ObservableCollection. 
    //So here we go through every instance to find which one this stepper is related to.
    
    var stepper = (Stepper)sender;
    foreach (Cloth cloth in vm.ShoppingBagCollection) 
    {
        if(cloth == stepper.BindingContext)
        {
            cloth.Price = cloth.Price / e.OldValue * e.NewValue;
        }
        pricetotal += cloth.Price;
    }   
    vm.PriceTotal = pricetotal; // // the total price shown in the entry, we will define it later in ViewModel. It also changes while stepper changes.
}
```

In your Model Cloth, also make some changes. You should implements INotifyPropertyChanged and PropertyChanged event. For more information about INotifyPropertyChanged, you could refer to [ViewModels and Property-Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications)

```
public class Cloth : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double _price;
    public double Price 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _price;
        }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Price)));
        }              
    }
    ......
```

}

Finally, in ViewModel, define a new property *PriceTotal* to which entry binds and also implememt the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class MainPageViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
    private double _priceTotal;
    
    public double PriceTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return _priceTotal;
        }
        set
        {
            _priceTotal = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PriceTotal)));
        }
    } 
.......
}
```

This is the main structure of my solution although I know there should be more details.

Hope my answer could help you.

Comment: thanks your code worked for me well though the entry is set to 0 even when cart has items unless stepper is pressed. Is there away to also solve this because it seems the same logic doesn't apply in the cs file  constructor . But your answer is okay. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. There're many details should be considered. From my point of view, once adding a new cloth in the ShoppingBagCollection, we should count the totalprice in the viewmodel again.

Comment: yeah that also worked fine for me. I was only concentrating on initializing it from the constructor but this is great. Thank you for giving me a warm welcome to stack overflow, C# and .NET MAUI.